# Codeigniter - Forgot to make an admin folder in controller and just created an admin.php controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a controller called `admin.php` and placed it in the `controllers` folder. I was working on this "users" system where I was coding the things to edit, create, manage users. I made functions like `users`, `edit_user`, etc so when visited, it looked like `http://localhost/admin/users`, `http://localhost/admin/edit_user`
I am finally done that part.

Now, I am working on the site section of my panel where I will be able to edit the site. I just realized that I needed to create an 'admin' folder in the controllers folder so I could make a brand new `users.php` controller and place all my functions for managing users there.

I have no idea what to do. I don't want to put everything from the admin panel in a single `admin.php` file. I tried creating a new `admin` folder but I realized I have to change the url's to everything.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean really but if you have to separate controllers, why not just use different names, like manage_website and manage_users... why there should be exactly 2 users.php?